# How to disable putting black frames between concatenated media with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

I am using the concat demuxer in ffmpeg. I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy out.mkv
```

and it works, except that it adds short gaps of black frames in between the concatenated files (there are three of them). How do I make it stop? If it helps, the audio is cut at those points, too.

I know that a parameter for this exists, but I can't find the original question anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the results of `ffprobe input` for all three files and also the content of concat.txt

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the "streams do not have exactly the same length". You have to specify the range to include for the items in `concat.txt`. Try specifying the `duration` or `outpoint` or `in point`:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat

> The duration of each file is used to adjust the timestamps of the next file: if the duration is incorrect (because it was computed using the bit-rate or because the file is truncated, for example), it can cause artifacts. The duration directive can be used to override the duration stored in each file.

Comment: From the Q - *in between the concatenated files* - so not within the files.

Comment: Don't use `duration` - it is meant to override the value the concat demuxer uses for calculation, not for trimming -use. `outpoint` for that.